# Cannot implicity convert type <string> to String[]

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I was trying to build a twitter bot for the Windows IOT Core.
I want to get the tweets from a file called tweets.csv.
The first step is to get a random line from the file.
This is what I tried:

```
         private String TweetString(int Size = 140)
     {
         string[] lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Path\tweets.csv"); //Error here
         System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
         var r = new Random();
         int randomLine = r.Next(0, lines.Length);
         string line = lines.Skip(randomLine - 1).Take(1).First();
         return builder.ToString();
     }
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

(Sorry, English is not my native language!)

Comment: ReadLines returns an IEnumerable not an array of strings. You need to materialize the IEnumerable to get the Array. Just add the ToArray() at the end of File.ReadLines

Comment: Convert it to an array.string[] test = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Path\tweets.csv").ToArray()

Comment: By the way, _lines_ is an array. To get an element of the array you don't need all that Linq code. Just _lines[randomLine ]_

Comment: Finally you are returning an empty string here. StringBuilder is never initialized to anything

Comment: Apart from everything 'File.ReadLines(@"C:\Path\tweets.csv")' is nothing good in UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ:

Ensure you have

```
using System.Linq;
```

and use `.ToArray()`.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Path\tweets.csv").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

use `File.ReadAllLines()` to read all lines and assign it as `string[]`

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert it to an array.

`string[] test = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Path\tweets.csv").ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are not actually using the variable as an array you could simply use the `var` key word and update the method to....

```
Random random = new Random();
private String TweetString(int Size = 140) {
    var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Path\tweets.csv"); //Note *var*
    var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();         
    int randomLine = random.Next(0, lines.Length);
    string line = lines.Skip(randomLine - 1).Take(1).First();
    builder.AppendLine(line);//Add the line to the builder.
    return builder.ToString();
}
```